# Remove links from text file

Tags: regex, sed, html-parsing

how can I remove links from a raw html text? I've got:

```
Foo bar <a href="http://www.foo.com">blah</a> bar foo
```

and want to get:

Foo bar blah bar foo

afterwards.

Comment: are you working with a particular language

Comment: Is it from a text file, with a handful of links, or is it fully generic html? If the latter and you just want something quick and cheap, look into `w3m -dump` or `lynx -dump`. If you want a repeatable or configurable tool, Brian's answer is right, find an HTML parser for the environment you want to use.

Comment: @spinon - he's using "SED" [Stream Editor] - UNIX... @Marko... putting REGEX at the beginning of his question won't solve his problem

Comment: yeah I figured it was something I wasn't familiar with. Because surely that wasn't a made up tag. I obviously know nothing about that. :)

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: @Marko: You shouldn't necessarily prefix your question title with something — that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to parse HTML with regexps, and [this won't work in all but the simplest cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), since HTML isn't regular. A much more reliable solution is to use an HTML parser. Numerous exist, for many different languages.

Comment: This is a pretty simple case though. You're not parsing the HTML so much as stripping a specific string (`</a>`) and any strings matching a specific pattern (`<a ... >`) from a block of text. This type of manipulation is precisely what regexp is designed for. None of aspects of HTML which make it _non-regular_ come into play (i.e. anchors can't be nested within one another, and we don't care about any other tags).

Comment: But do you care about tags in comments etc.?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -re 's|<a [^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|\1|g'
```

But Brian's answer is right: This should only be used in very simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
sed -e 's/<a[^>]*>.*<\/a>//g' test.txt
```

Comment: This would produce "Foo bar  bar foo" instead of "Foo bar blah bar foo" for the example in question.  See danlei's solution for the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

`$ echo 'Foo bar <a href="http://www.foo.com">blah</a> bar foo' | awk 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"}/<a href/{gsub(/<a href=\042.*\042>/,"")}1'`

Foo bar blah
 bar foo